# GFCI + Switch + 4 sets of wires

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet and switch in same box. The box has 4 sets of wires- power source, light, and two others. The switch controls a light. When I replaced the outlet with a GFCI, everything worked expect that the switch was turning the GFCI on and off. The GFCI was wired without the load out- just line in. All the wires were pig tailed. I believe I need to identify the set of wires that goes to the light to rewire the GFCI, but am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Upload pictures of the wires going to everything.

Comment: By chance, do any of the white wires have black tape on them?  Sometimes a switch loop (that would go to a light) is marked with black tape.

Comment: "The GFCI was wired without the load out" -- does that mean you left the warning tape on the LOAD terminals and only used LINE terminals?  Where did you connect the neutral to the switch cable?

Comment: The first time I wired it like this and ended up with the switch controlling the outlet and light: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a2/87/50/a28750cfa91f315f79a8646403f87a4a.gif This matched how it was wired when it was just a regular outlet, not GFCI. The additional white and black wires were pig tailed. There were no taped wires to mark the switch loop.

Comment: Can you post actual photos of the wiring?